# I'm facing a problem with CardView, and Material Design elevation, when view's background is changed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I'm trying to change the background of `CardView`, or it's child, which covers whole area of `CardView`,
the elevation shadow disappears.

However, when I used `app:contentPadding` attribute, the elevation
shadows became visible again, but now I have this weird padding on [CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrhdp.jpg), which is of course, not great to see. I found out, that views of Material Design also have such a problem.
Here is a [MaterialToolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJphd.jpg) without background, and here is [with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3yxF.jpg) background. Here's my XML code below.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            >
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="232dp"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_news_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/numans"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorToolBarDarkSeaBlue"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_news_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And Here is the code with MaterialToolbar

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a drawable with a corner radius of the card's inner radius,set it as the background of the layout inside the cardview.you can then adjust the layout's margin or backgrounds corner radius to tweek the view of the shadow.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#2e8b57" />


<corners android:radius="5dp"/>




</shape>
```

Comment: That worked! You just made my day man. Thank you very much!